# option menu and context menu

Tags: android, menu

i have listview the fisrt time i when i click to row it open the context menu then  i override the oncontextitemselected

```
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch(item.getItemId()) {

        case CALL_ID:
        {
        AdapterContextMenuInfo info2 = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();

        String phone=mDbHelper.getPhone(info2.id);
        String toDial="tel:"+phone.toString();

        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL,Uri.parse(toDial)));
        return true;
        }
    }
    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}
```

this do correctly but when i

```
public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
        switch(item.getItemId()) {
        case CALL_ID:
        {
        AdapterContextMenuInfo info2 = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();

        String phone=mDbHelper.getPhone(info2.id);
        String toDial="tel:"+phone.toString();

        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL,Uri.parse(toDial)));
        return true;
        }
        return super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item);
    }
}
```

the app crashed can u show me the difference between them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

**context_menu.xml** (res/menu/context_menu.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/call"
          android:title="CALL" />
</menu>
```

**Context Menu:**

```
@Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
        info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo)menuInfo;
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.context_menu, menu);
    }   
 @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.call: 

            String phone="555-555-555";
            String toDial="tel:"+phone.toString();

            Uri uri = Uri.parse(toDial);
            Intent it = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, uri);  
            startActivity(it);  

        return true;

        default:
            return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission  android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"></uses-permission>
```

That should work.